# Как отследить движение цвета

Tags: python, autohotkey

Всем привет начал изучать AHK на практике и столкнулся с задачей   как можно отследить изменения
цвета на участке вот пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно  отследить движение или не движение    синей полосы   нужно выполнять действие в зависимости от поведения этой полоски если она не движется  1 действие  если движется 2
помогите советом  как это можно  реализовать на  AHK   или  Python
или  хотя б  как правильно задать вопрос в Гугле

Comment: Пока нашёл только вариант с нахождение первой точки коричневого цвета и проверять на его изменение но не могу это в код записать

Comment: В каком окне - находится движение или не движение синей полосы? Какой программы?